# scikit-learn LinearRegression IndexError

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, linear-regression, index-error

I am working on a **LinearRegression** model to fill the null values for the feature `Rupeepersqft`. When I run the code, I am receiving this error:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-33d4e6d2998e> in <module>()
      1 test_data = data_with_null.iloc[:,:3]
----> 2 Rupeepersqft_predicted['Rupeepersqft'] = pd.DataFrame(linreg.predict(test_data))

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

This is the code which gives me the error:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
linreg = LinearRegression()

data_with_null = data2[['Price (Lakhs)','Area','Area Type','Rupeepersqft','Condition','Purchase Type','Real Estate Regulation Act']].dropna()
data_without_null =  data_with_null.dropna()

train_data_x = data_without_null.iloc[:,:3]
train_data_y = data_without_null.iloc[:,3]

linreg.fit(train_data_x, train_data_y)

test_data = data_with_null.iloc[:,:3]
Rupeepersqft_predicted['Rupeepersqft'] = pd.DataFrame(linreg.predict(test_data))

data_with_null.Rupeepersqft.fillna(Rupeepersqft_predicted, inplace=True)
```

This is how the data looks like:

[image: Data2]

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: `Rupeepersqft_predicted['Rupeepersqft']` would be ok if it is selecting a column from a dataframe (of value from a `dict`).  But apparently it is an array, which doesn't accept string indexing (unless it's a structured array).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To assign values to a column in `Pandas.DataFrame` you should use the `locators`, i.e., `loc` and `iloc` (for array-like manipulations), so to fix your issue try changing the

```
Rupeepersqft_predicted['Rupeepersqft'] = pd.DataFrame(linreg.predict(test_data))
```

to:

```
Rupeepersqft_predicted.loc[:, 'Rupeepersqft'] = pd.DataFrame(linreg.predict(test_data))
```

which will chose all the rows (the `:`), and the column `Rupeepersqft`, and assign whatever values you have on the right.

or by using the `iloc`:

```
Rupeepersqft_predicted.iloc[:, 1] = pd.DataFrame(linreg.predict(test_data))
```

to assign it to the all rows (again by `:` operator) of the `1`st column of the `DataFrame`.

Just make sure the values on the right are of the same length as the column you try to assign it to.

More on `Pandas` you can find in [this book](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/03.00-introduction-to-pandas.html).

Cheers

Comment: You are welcome, and I'm really happy it helped you. Please consider accepting this answer (by clicking the "v" next to the answer) to let other people, which encounter the same issue, know that it solves it. Cheers mate.